# Parse json to especific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How i can parse this json

```
[
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"1","TOTAL":78},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"2","TOTAL":122},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"3","TOTAL":102},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"4","TOTAL":65},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"5","TOTAL":134},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"6","TOTAL":88},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"7","TOTAL":77},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"8","TOTAL":58},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"9","TOTAL":67},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"10","TOTAL":69},

{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"5","TOTAL":4},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"6","TOTAL":87},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"7","TOTAL":81},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"8","TOTAL":105},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"9","TOTAL":112},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"10","TOTAL":85},
]
```

To this format

```
 series: [{
            name: '1',
            data: [78, 122, 102, 65, 134, 88, 77, 58, 67, 69, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: '2',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 87, 81, 105, 112, 85, 0, 0]
        }]
```

With an javascript or jquery function efficiently? 
In the Json every row represents a total value for each code (1 or 2) per month

For the CODE=1 i have totals only for ten months (month 1 = jan, month 2= feb ... month 10= oct)

For the CODE=2  i have totals only for five months between may and octuber.

In this array [78, 122, 102, 65, 134, 88, 77, 58, 67, 69, 0, 0]
78 is the total for january, 122 for february, 102 for march ...

For those months that i  do not have a total,  like november or december for example , i need to put a 0

My json will return more info, with more codes i can't use brute force

Thanks in advance
JC

Comment: So the `month` attribute is omitted..?

Comment: Yes the month  attribute is omitted, that only says which is the position of that element in the array. I try to do a for each cycle , but can it be done with a map ?

Comment: @josmarycarrero Where does the `0`'s come from..? BTW you've an extra `,` in your array.

Comment: @TJ the 0's represent every month for which i do not have data

Comment: @josmarycarrero *" i do not have data"* - What do you mean by data..? In your sample data, everything have all attributes. How we were supposed to know unless you describe properly..? Please [edit] the question and update it properly...

Answer (score 1):

You can run a loop like the following:

```
var temp = [];
for (var i =0; i<  data.length;i++) {
    var obj = data[i],
        dup = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
        var item = temp[j];
        if (obj.CODE == item.name) {
            item.data.push(obj.TOTAL);
            dup = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!dup) {
        temp.push({
            name: obj.CODE,
            data: [obj.TOTAL]
        });
    }
}
```

---

```js
var data = [{
    "CODE": "1",
    "MONTH": "1",
    "TOTAL": 78
  }, {
    "CODE": "1",
    "MONTH": "2",
    "TOTAL": 122
  }, {
    "CODE": "1",
    "MONTH": "3",
    "TOTAL": 102
  }, {
    "CODE": "1",
    "MONTH": "4",
    "TOTAL": 65
  }, {
    "CODE": "1",
    "MONTH": "5",
    "TOTAL": 134
  }, {
    "CODE": "1",
    "MONTH": "6",
    "TOTAL": 88
  }, {
    "CODE": "1",
    "MONTH": "7",
    "TOTAL": 77
  }, {
    "CODE": "1",
    "MONTH": "8",
    "TOTAL": 58
  }, {
    "CODE": "1",
    "MONTH": "9",
    "TOTAL": 67
  }, {
    "CODE": "1",
    "MONTH": "10",
    "TOTAL": 69
  },

  {
    "CODE": "2",
    "MONTH": "5",
    "TOTAL": 4
  }, {
    "CODE": "2",
    "MONTH": "6",
    "TOTAL": 87
  }, {
    "CODE": "2",
    "MONTH": "7",
    "TOTAL": 81
  }, {
    "CODE": "2",
    "MONTH": "8",
    "TOTAL": 105
  }, {
    "CODE": "2",
    "MONTH": "9",
    "TOTAL": 112
  }, {
    "CODE": "2",
    "MONTH": "10",
    "TOTAL": 85
  }
];
var temp = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var obj = data[i],
    dup = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
    var item = temp[j];
    if (obj.CODE == item.name) {
      item.data.push(obj.TOTAL);
      dup = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!dup) {
    temp.push({
      name: obj.CODE,
      data: [obj.TOTAL]
    });
  }
}
console.log(temp);
```

```html
<p>Check browser console <sup>F12</sup> to see the result<p>
```

Comment: I agree the above code is more robust.

Comment: @E.Maggini then you can simply upvote it... :)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks so much for your help! I complete your solution and i get what a want. But how can i do it more robust? This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/josmaryc/yfy1juec/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force example which does only what was requested.

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odoxxrhd/1/)

```
var originalData = [
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"1","TOTAL":78},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"2","TOTAL":122},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"3","TOTAL":102},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"4","TOTAL":65},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"5","TOTAL":134},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"6","TOTAL":88},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"7","TOTAL":77},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"8","TOTAL":58},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"9","TOTAL":67},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"10","TOTAL":69},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"5","TOTAL":4},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"6","TOTAL":87},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"7","TOTAL":81},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"8","TOTAL":105},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"9","TOTAL":112},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"10","TOTAL":85},
];

var newData={};

var tempData1=[];
var tempData2=[];

for (var ii=0;ii<originalData.length;ii++){



    if (originalData[ii].CODE==="1"){

        tempData1.push(originalData[ii].TOTAL);
    }
    else{
        tempData2.push(originalData[ii].TOTAL);
    }

}

newData['series'] =[ {name: '1',
                 data: tempData1},
                     {
                         name: '2',
                 data: tempData2
                     }];


console.log(JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is my solution, how can improve it? jsfiddle.net/josmaryc/yfy1juec.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var oData = [
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"1","TOTAL":78},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"2","TOTAL":122},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"3","TOTAL":102},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"4","TOTAL":65},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"5","TOTAL":134},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"6","TOTAL":88},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"7","TOTAL":77},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"8","TOTAL":58},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"9","TOTAL":67},
{"CODE":"1","MONTH":"10","TOTAL":69},

{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"5","TOTAL":4},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"6","TOTAL":87},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"7","TOTAL":81},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"8","TOTAL":105},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"9","TOTAL":112},
{"CODE":"2","MONTH":"10","TOTAL":85},
],
  nData = [{ name: '1', data: [] }, { name: '2', data: [] }];
for (var n = 1; n <= 12; n++) {
  var d1 = oData.filter(function(d) {
      return d.CODE == '1' && d.MONTH == n;
    }),
    d2 = oData.filter(function(d) {
      return d.CODE == '2' && d.MONTH == n;
    });

  nData[0].data.push(d1.length ? d1[0].TOTAL : 0);
  nData[1].data.push(d2.length ? d2[0].TOTAL : 0);
}
$('pre.out').text( JSON.stringify(nData) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is my solution, how can improve it? jsfiddle.net/josmaryc/yfy1juec

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by improvement. If you have a specific question or error, I'd be glad to take a look. Otherwise you may want to check with Codereview.